# UI issue on company page in Jobs

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

In the Jobs section on the company page, the name of the company is overlapped with the company link if the link is long.

[image: Overlapping company name with URL]

Here's the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/www-db-com-careers-en-prof-about-technology-india-html) of the page.

Comment: That's a bug in the german language.

Comment: Not this time, @Will. It's a simple case of epically-long-url.com. None of the words in the link are even in German.

Comment: ... ... .... yeah, but still...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for bringing this issue to our attention!  It is now fixed.